# How to get tab index from click on textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a problem. I want to get a tabIndex of textbox, when I click on him.
The problem is ,that I need to use `private void klik(object sender, EventArgs e)` and there is nothing like TabControl1.SelectedTab which I found out on google. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you explain if you are looking for the TabIndex property (the tab order) or the Index of the TabPage that hosts the TextBox?

Comment: @Steve I'm looking for TabIndex of existing property

Comment: So you are simply looking for the TextBox tabindex. If this is the case the answer from @eXpresso is the correct one. Please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your sender object is of the type `TextBox`, so you can cast it into a new `TextBox` object, and access it's tabindex.

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
     int tabIndex = tb.TabIndex;
}
```

Comment: A safer version of the body of this method is: `if (sender is TextBox tb) { int tabIndex = tb.TabIndex; }`. Even prettyer: `int tabIndex = (sender is TextBox tb)?.TabIndex ?? -1;`